# How to make vml work inside wine?

Tags: internet-explorer, wine

VML doesn't work in any version of Internet Explorer in wine. I see just white rectangles instead of VML graphics.

How to make VML work?

**Update:**
setting `vgx.dll` to 'native' partially solves the problem (rendering is weird sometimes).

Answer (score 2):

> Vector Markup Language (VML) is a deprecated XML language used to produce vector graphics.
>   VML was submitted as a proposed standard to the W3C in 1998 [...] development of the format ceased in 1998 [...] VML is still available in Internet Explorer 9 but Microsoft expects web sites to transition to SVG in the future

It might not be possible to find anyone with the skills and motivation to make IE's VML support functional under Wine.

> How to make VML work?

The only way I can think of is:

1. Find out how IE's VML support is implemented (some MS DLL?)
2. Learn how WINE provides that sort of support.
3. Find some VML specifications
4. Look for an open source VML implementation
5. Write software

I would fail at step 1.